# discretization error in numerical

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I have been able to find the formula to approximate $f''(x_0)$ which uses $f( x_0),f\left(x_0+\frac{h}{2}\right)$ and $f(x+2h)$ with some help, which is the following:

$$f''(x_0)
=\frac{f(x_0+2h)-4f(x_0+h/2)+3f(x_0)}{\frac32h^2}.$$

> Now I am trying to find the formula for the leading term in the discretization error.

Is this the proper equation to use to find this?

$$E(h) = f''_{exact} - f''(h) \approx Ah^p$$ where $h$ is a measure of the mesh discretization, $A$ is a constant, and $p$ is the rate of convergence. If so how can I use this formula with my given answer from above?

Comment: What is $f_{exact}?$ Obviously not $f(x_0)$. Do you mean $E = f''_{exact} - f''(h)?$

Comment: @gammatester yes sorry that was a typo I will edit that in. Would you be able to help me out with this question

Comment: Still unclear. If we write $$f''(x_0,h) =\frac{f(x_0+2h)-4f(x_0+h/2)+3f(x_0)}{\frac32h^2},$$
can get the $f''(x_0) - f''(x_0,h)$ by expanding $f$ as a Taylor series at $x=x_0.$

Comment: It's your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plugin the Taylor expansion
$$f(x_0+h/2) = f(x_0) + \frac{1}{2}h f'(x_0)+ \frac{1}{8}h^2 f''(x_0) +
\frac{1}{48}h^3 f'''(x_0) + \frac{1}{384}h^4 f''''(x_0)+ O(h^5)$$
and similar 
$$f(x_0+2h) = f(x_0) +2hf'(x_0) + 2h^2f''(x_0) + \frac{4}{3}h^3f'''(x_0) + \frac{2}{3}h^4f''''(x_0) + O(h^5) $$ into you formula your get
$$f''(x_0) = f''(x_0,h) + \frac{5}{6}f'''(x_0)h + O(h^2)$$ from which you read-off
$$f''(x_0)-f''(x_0, h) = \frac{5}{6}f'''(x_0)h + O(h^2)$$ 
and therefore

> $$A=\frac{5}{6}f'''(x_0), \quad p=1$$

Comment: and how do I use this to find the formula for the leading term in the discretization error

Comment: so is the formula for the leading term $$f''(x_0) = f''(x_0,h) + \frac{5}{6}f'''(x_0)h + O(h^2)$$? do I need to use those values you listed after and plug in somewhere

Comment: so the leading term is $\frac{5}{6}f'''(x_0)$ and the order of approximation that in $O(h^p)$ is $1$?

Comment: I don't have a dog in this fight, but if you can't recognize the leading term in the discretization error from what's been done here, you should probably go back and review the definition of "discretization error" and the notion of "leading term" until you understand them.

Comment: is my last comment correct?

Comment: just trying to understand this concept

Comment: Your comment should read $\frac{5}{6}f'''(x_0)h + O(h^2),$ and therefore by your **definition** of $A,p$ the values listed.

Comment: okay so the leading term is $\frac{5}{6}f'''(x_0)h+O(h^2)$ is the leading term in the discretization error and 1 is the order of approx

Comment: No, the $O(h^2)$ is not included in the leading term.

Comment: okay that's what I thought, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ is sufficiently smooth around $x_0$, one can use the Taylor series to write for all $x$ close enough to $x_0$:

$$f(x_0+h)= f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h + \frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)h^2 + \mathcal{O}(h^3)$$

Using these one can expand the terms in your formula as follows

(A) $f(x_0+2h)=f(x_0) + f'(x_0)2h + 2f''(x_0)h^2 + \mathcal{O}(h^3)$

(B) $f(x_0+h/2)=f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h/2 + \frac{1}{8}f''(x_0)h^2 + \mathcal{O}(h^3)$

Plugging these into the formula you gave one can write

$$\frac{f(x_0+2h) - 4f(x_0+h/2) + 3f(x_0) + \mathcal{O}(h^3)}{3/2h^2} = \frac{ f(x_0) + f'(x_0)2h + 2f''(x_0)h^2 - 4(f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h/2 + \frac{1}{8}f''(x_0)h^2) + 3f(x_0) + \mathcal{O}(h^3)}{3/2h^2} = \frac{ f(x_0) + 2f'(x_0)h + 2f''(x_0)h^2 - 4f(x_0) - 2f'(x_0)h - \frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)h^2 + 3f(x_0) + \mathcal{O}(h^3)}{3/2h^2} = f''(x_0) + \mathcal{O}(h). $$

This should give enough of a lead to give you the result. If not, it is possible to expand a discussion in the comments..

Comment: then how do I use this to find the formula for the leading term in the discretization error

Comment: You can see that the formulae I gave still shown that there is an $h$ term. This means that if you make a Talor series expansion around $x_0$ and modify it in a clever way (as above) then you get $\frac{f(x_0+2h) - 4f(x_0+h/2) + 3f(x_0)}{3/2h^2} - f''(x_0) = \mathcal{O}(h)$. 

As @gammatester suggested above, this implies that the order is not 2, because the difference we calculated is not constant wrt $h$. Indeed, one has to take one order higher Taylor series to obtain the constant term - this gives order $p=1$ of the scheme as the approximation of $f''(x_0)$. This is already done above.

Comment: okay then this answer and @gammatesters answers are complete solutions

Comment: so the leading term is $\frac{5}{6}f'''(x_0)$ and the order of approximation is $1$?

Comment: Indeed. gammamaster has it all written in his answer.

EDIT: My previous comment sais "this implies that the order is not 2" but what I really meant was that "this implies that the Taylor expansion of order 2  is not enough". It should be clear from context, but just in case.

Comment: thanks for your help!